# How to prevent that import with Feeds and Elysia cron gets stuck

Tags: 7, feeds, cron

I have several [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) which are called by [Elysia cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron).
The feeds are called at a given time, and later the last two feeds are called each 2 minutes, because it was the only way of preventing them from stopping. However, when data has increased in size and complexity, the cron process is stopped because one or both of the last Feeds are stuck and never ending.

I have seen that by updating the database table `elysia_cron` by setting the field `running` to 0, the Feeds are completed.

So my idea was to create a daemon to regularly update the process and thus prevent the hanging of the Feeds process.

What am I missing, shouldn't this check had been already incorporated into the module itself? What other ideas could prevent the failed import?

Comment: I believe on of the bugs of feeds is that it can't handle large import files. How big are your files?

Comment: 1.62 Mb. Maybe I should split it in several files (really http served data), and somehow control if the previous data has been processed, in order to feed more new data, with smaller size?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that temporarily switching off the modules [PathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [SubPathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) improved the speed x10, making all these problems dissapear forever. No more feeds stuck or hanged. Later, I enable the modules again, and everything is ready.